# Отличие UniformGrid от Grid

Tags: wpf, c#

Хочу заменить в своем WPF приложении контрол Grid на более подходящий UniformGrid. Однако после замены(вроде бы эквивалентной) получаю смещения в расположении контента по ячейкам и повторы. Подскажите в чем различие этих контролов и с чем может быть связано такое поведение?

Answer (score 2):

UniformGrid сильно отличается от Grid и очень ограничен. Он автоматически размещает элементы в сетке с определённым размером, изменяя размер, а также количество строк и столбцов при добавлении элементов управления. Ячейки всегда имеют одинаковый размер. Этот элемент удобно применять для быстрого создания сетки с унифицированным размером (шахматная доска, кнопки калькулятора). Количество строк и столбцов можно присвоить вручную. В таком случае, если количество дочерних элементов превысит количество ячеек, эти элементы отражаться не будут. Если задать лишь кол-во строк, то по мере увеличения дочерних элементов будет увеличиваться и кол-во столбцов.